# Switch tabs with click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to build a page with a sidebar and have it where I click one of the links at the top and it switches the tab and the content within it. The current formula that I have isn't working and I get one error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')

I have provided my code below. Thanks!:

```js
function switchTabs(){
    document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const menuBar = link.parentElement;
            const tabsContainer = menuBar.parentElement;
            const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
            const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(`.content[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`);

            menuBar.querySelector(".tab-button").forEach(link => {
                link.classList.remove("tabs-button-active");
            })

            tabsContainer.querySelector(".content").forEach(tab => {
                tab.classList.remove("content-active");
            })

            link.classList.add(".tab-button-active");
            tabToActivate.classList.add(".content-active");
        });
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    switchTabs();

    document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {
        tabsContainer.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click();
    })
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
:root {
  --c-text-primary: #282a32;
  --c-text-secondary: #686b87;
  --c-text-action: #404089;
  --c-accent-primary: #434ce8;
  --c-border-primary: #eff1f6;
  --c-background-primary: #ffffff;
  --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
  --c-background-tertiary: #ecf3fe;
  --c-background-quaternary: #e9ecf4;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
  background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
  color: var(--c-text-primary);
}


:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-nav{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #A388E7 !important;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item{
  color: #686868 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: -1675px !important;
}
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}

#alert{
  position: relative;
  right: -3px !important;
}

.action {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}

.action .profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action .profile img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.action .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.action .menu.active {
  top: 80px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action .menu h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.action .menu h3 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cecece;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.action .menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.action .menu ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #9370DB;
}


.responsive-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
}
.button i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.button span {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}



.main {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .main-header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}
.search input {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em 0 36px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}
.search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input::placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:focus, .search input:hover {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.search button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.horizontal-tabs {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .horizontal-tabs {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  .horizontal-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
.horizontal-tabs a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.horizontal-tabs a:hover, .horizontal-tabs a:focus, .horizontal-tabs a.active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  border-bottom-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.horizontal-tabs a + * {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.content-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
}

.content-header-intro h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.content-header-intro p {
  color: var(--c-text-secondary);
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-header-actions a:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.content-active {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}


 

.content-panel {
  display: none;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-panel {
    display: block;
  }
}

.vertical-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.vertical-tabs a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.vertical-tabs a:hover, .vertical-tabs a:focus, .vertical-tabs a.active {
  background-color: var(--c-background-tertiary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.vertical-tabs a + * {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.content-main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
       column-gap: 1.5rem;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 1rem 1.25rem;
}
.card-header div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.card-header div span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card-header div span img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.card-header div h3 {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 99em;
  background-color: var(--c-background-quaternary);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle input {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
          clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
.toggle input:checked + span {
  background-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.toggle input:checked + span:before {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
}
.toggle input:focus + span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--c-background-tertiary);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
.card-footer a {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--c-text-primary);
  border: 4px solid var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 99em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>StudioPick</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  

</head>
<body>
<!---Navbar--->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item2">
                <div class="action">
                  <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                    <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted" id="userType" style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: -60px; font-size: 12px !important">Studio</p>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit profile</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!---Navbar--->
<main class="main">
    <div class="responsive-wrapper">
        <div class="main-header">
            <h1>Settings</h1>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-tabs">
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="1">Profile</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="2">My Rooms</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="3">Session Management</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="4">Payment History</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="5">Edit Payment</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content" data-tab="1">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Manage your profile</h2>
                    <p>Edit your profile information such email, username, password, etc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="content-header-intro">
                <h2>Manage your studio rooms</h2>
                <p>Add, delete, and edit the room images for your studio profile.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-header-actions">
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
                    <span>Filters</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
                    <span>Add a room</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content" data-tab="2">
            <div class="content-panel">
                <div class="vertical-tabs">
                    <a href="#" class="active">View Rooms</a>
                    <a href="#">Manage Services</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/zeplin.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room A</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/github.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room B</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/figma.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room C</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</main>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/phosphor-icons'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

  <script>
    function menuToggle() {
      const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  </script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem and i hope this similar as you expect
first, fix your css code:

- You add class tab-button-active to your css code to active link when click:

  .tab-button-active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
  }
- Update your css code to content and code when content active. This will similar code and display none and active with display: flex !important, code below:

  ```
  .content {
      border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
      margin-top: 2rem;
      display: none;
    }
  ```

  .content-active {
  display: flex !important;
  }

second, fix some errors in javascript code:

- You can replace querySelector with querySelectorAll to select all elements with you query, here are errors code:

  ```
  menuBar.querySelector(".tab-button").forEach(link => {
                link.classList.remove("tabs-button-active");
            })

            tabsContainer.querySelector(".content").forEach(tab => {
                tab.classList.remove("content-active");
            })
  ```
- Some spelling mistakes: "tab-button-active" similar className you add when active not "tabs-button-active"

  ```
   link.classList.remove("tabs-button-active");
  ```
- tabsContainer doesn't contain tab-button so you can't querySelector on this, below is the fix code:

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  switchTabs();

  ```
  document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {

    document.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click()
  })
  ```

  });

Here are my code, hope it useful for you:

```js
function switchTabs() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {

link.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const menuBar = link.parentElement;
  const tabsContainer = menuBar.parentElement;
  const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(`[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`)



  menuBar.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {

    link.classList.remove("tab-button-active");
  })

  tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove("content-active");
  })
  link.classList.add("tab-button-active");
 
  tabToActivate.classList.add("content-active");
});
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  switchTabs();

  document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {

document.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click()
  })
});
```

```css
   @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
:root {
  --c-text-primary: #282a32;
  --c-text-secondary: #686b87;
  --c-text-action: #404089;
  --c-accent-primary: #434ce8;
  --c-border-primary: #eff1f6;
  --c-background-primary: #ffffff;
  --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
  --c-background-tertiary: #ecf3fe;
  --c-background-quaternary: #e9ecf4;
}



body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
  background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
  color: var(--c-text-primary);
}



:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-nav{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #A388E7 !important;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item{
  color: #686868 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: -1675px !important;
}
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}

#alert{
  position: relative;
  right: -3px !important;
}

.action {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}

.action .profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action .profile img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.action .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.action .menu.active {
  top: 80px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action .menu h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.action .menu h3 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cecece;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.action .menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.action .menu ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #9370DB;
}


.responsive-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
}
.button i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.button span {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}



.main {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .main-header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}
.search input {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em 0 36px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}
.search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input::placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:focus, .search input:hover {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.search button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.horizontal-tabs {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .horizontal-tabs {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  .horizontal-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
.horizontal-tabs a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.horizontal-tabs a:hover, .horizontal-tabs a:focus, .horizontal-tabs a.active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  border-bottom-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.horizontal-tabs a + * {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.content-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
}

.content-header-intro h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.content-header-intro p {
  color: var(--c-text-secondary);
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-header-actions a:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: none;
}

.content-active {
  
  display: flex !important;
}


 

.content-panel {
  display: none;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-panel {
    display: block;
  }
}

.vertical-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.vertical-tabs a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.vertical-tabs a:hover, .vertical-tabs a:focus, .vertical-tabs a.active {
  background-color: var(--c-background-tertiary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.vertical-tabs a + * {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.content-main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
       column-gap: 1.5rem;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 1rem 1.25rem;
}
.card-header div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.card-header div span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card-header div span img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.card-header div h3 {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 99em;
  background-color: var(--c-background-quaternary);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle input {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
          clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
.toggle input:checked + span {
  background-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.toggle input:checked + span:before {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
}
.toggle input:focus + span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--c-background-tertiary);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
.card-footer a {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.tab-button-active{
  color: var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--c-accent-primary) !important; 
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--c-text-primary);
  border: 4px solid var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 99em;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>StudioPick</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  

</head>
<body>
<!---Navbar--->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item2">
                <div class="action">
                  <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                    <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted" id="userType" style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: -60px; font-size: 12px !important">Studio</p>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit profile</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!---Navbar--->
<main class="main">
    <div class="responsive-wrapper">
        <div class="main-header">
            <h1>Settings</h1>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-tabs">
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="1">Profile</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="2">My Rooms</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="3">Session Management</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="4">Payment History</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="5">Edit Payment</a>
        </div>
        
<div class="content" data-tab="1" >
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Manage your profile</h2>
                    <p>Edit your profile information such email, username, password, etc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="content-header-intro">
                <h2>Manage your studio rooms</h2>
                <p>Add, delete, and edit the room images for your studio profile.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-header-actions">
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
                    <span>Filters</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
                    <span>Add a room</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content" data-tab="2">
            <div class="content-panel">
                <div class="vertical-tabs">
                    <a href="#" class="active">View Rooms</a>
                    <a href="#">Manage Services</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/zeplin.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room A</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/github.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room B</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/figma.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room C</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</main>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/phosphor-icons'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

  <script>
    function menuToggle() {
      const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  </script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error here:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {
  console.log(tabsContainer);
  tabsContainer.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click();
})
```

There's no `horizontal-tabs` class in your `content` class.

So, when you use `tabsContainer.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button")` you got a null element.
Obviously, you call the `click` function on null element caught an error.

If you don't sure what elements you select, just print it on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure exactly what you want to do but I went until all errors had been solved.

Firstly, minor issue, you forgot to end the strong element:

```
<!-- old code -->
<a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
<!-- new code -->
<a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</strong></a>
```

You should be changing the above to `querySelectorAll` if you are intending to do a `forEach` on them as `querySelector` only returns one element.

```
//old code
menuBar.querySelector(".tab-button").forEach(link => {
      link.classList.remove("tabs-button-active");
})

tabsContainer.querySelector(".content").forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove("content-active");
})

//new code
menuBar.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {
      link.classList.remove("tabs-button-active");
})

tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove("content-active");
})
```

You should use `document` instead of `tabsContainer` for this as there are no `horizontal-tabs` under `tabsContainer` which is the reason you are getting the null issue you were initially talking about.

```
//old code
document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {
    tabsContainer.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click();
})

//new code
document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {
    document.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click();
})
```

Below is the fixed code:

```js
function switchTabs(){
document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const menuBar = link.parentElement;
        const tabsContainer = menuBar.parentElement;
        const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
        const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(`.content[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`);

        menuBar.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {
            link.classList.remove("tabs-button-active");
        })

        tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tab => {
            tab.classList.remove("content-active");
        })

        link.classList.add(".tab-button-active");
        tabToActivate.classList.add(".content-active");
    });
});
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
switchTabs();

document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {
    document.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click();
})
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
:root {
  --c-text-primary: #282a32;
  --c-text-secondary: #686b87;
  --c-text-action: #404089;
  --c-accent-primary: #434ce8;
  --c-border-primary: #eff1f6;
  --c-background-primary: #ffffff;
  --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
  --c-background-tertiary: #ecf3fe;
  --c-background-quaternary: #e9ecf4;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
  background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
  color: var(--c-text-primary);
}


:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-nav{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #A388E7 !important;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item{
  color: #686868 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: -1675px !important;
}
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}

#alert{
  position: relative;
  right: -3px !important;
}

.action {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}

.action .profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action .profile img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.action .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.action .menu.active {
  top: 80px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action .menu h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.action .menu h3 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cecece;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.action .menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.action .menu ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #9370DB;
}


.responsive-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
}
.button i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.button span {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}



.main {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .main-header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}
.search input {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em 0 36px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}
.search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input::placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:focus, .search input:hover {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.search button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.horizontal-tabs {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .horizontal-tabs {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  .horizontal-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
.horizontal-tabs a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.horizontal-tabs a:hover, .horizontal-tabs a:focus, .horizontal-tabs a.active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  border-bottom-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.horizontal-tabs a + * {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.content-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
}

.content-header-intro h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.content-header-intro p {
  color: var(--c-text-secondary);
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-header-actions a:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.content-active {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}


 

.content-panel {
  display: none;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-panel {
    display: block;
  }
}

.vertical-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.vertical-tabs a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.vertical-tabs a:hover, .vertical-tabs a:focus, .vertical-tabs a.active {
  background-color: var(--c-background-tertiary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.vertical-tabs a + * {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.content-main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
       column-gap: 1.5rem;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 1rem 1.25rem;
}
.card-header div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.card-header div span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card-header div span img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.card-header div h3 {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 99em;
  background-color: var(--c-background-quaternary);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle input {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
          clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
.toggle input:checked + span {
  background-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.toggle input:checked + span:before {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
}
.toggle input:focus + span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--c-background-tertiary);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
.card-footer a {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--c-text-primary);
  border: 4px solid var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 99em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>StudioPick</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  

</head>
<body>
<!---Navbar--->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</strong></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item2">
                <div class="action">
                  <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                    <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted" id="userType" style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: -60px; font-size: 12px !important">Studio</p>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit profile</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!---Navbar--->
<main class="main">
    <div class="responsive-wrapper">
        <div class="main-header">
            <h1>Settings</h1>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-tabs">
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="1">Profile</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="2">My Rooms</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="3">Session Management</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="4">Payment History</a>
            <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="5">Edit Payment</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content" data-tab="1">
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="content-header-intro">
                    <h2>Manage your profile</h2>
                    <p>Edit your profile information such email, username, password, etc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="content-header-intro">
                <h2>Manage your studio rooms</h2>
                <p>Add, delete, and edit the room images for your studio profile.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-header-actions">
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
                    <span>Filters</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
                    <span>Add a room</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content" data-tab="2">
            <div class="content-panel">
                <div class="vertical-tabs">
                    <a href="#" class="active">View Rooms</a>
                    <a href="#">Manage Services</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/zeplin.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room A</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/github.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room B</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/figma.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Room C</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Add room's content</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</main>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/phosphor-icons'></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

  <script>
    function menuToggle() {
      const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  </script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>
</html>
```